# How to get data from the CKEditor5's editor without the NBSP filler?

Tags: ckeditor5

An empty editor's `getData()` method returns an empty paragraph filled with the `&nbsp;`. There is a function `getDataWithoutFiller()` in the API but it's not a function available to use in the editor instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to check whether the editor is empty? There's no such option for now, but it should be implemented in the next iteration. The request for that functionality is in the https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/401.

The simple but not complete workaround would be to replace `&nbsp;` and other white spaces with an empty string and check then if there are only empty paragraphs.

Other than that, the `&nbsp;` in the non-empty content is important as otherwise, the created paragraphs would be 0px high.